# onCreateView method gets called when? and How many times in Activity life cycle?

Tags: android, logcat, lifecycle

I wrote a little program looking like this:

```
package com.example.lifecycle;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class LifeLogger extends Activity {

    private String TAG = this.getClass().getName().toString();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_life_logger);
        Log.d(TAG,"onCreate event");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(TAG,"onResume event");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.d(TAG,"onPause event");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(TAG,"onStop event");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        Log.d(TAG,"onRestart event");
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        Log.d(TAG,"onCreateView event");
        return super.onCreateView(name, context, attrs);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d(TAG,"onStart event");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG,"onDestroy event");
    }
}
```

Which is the main activity.

The LogCat is:

> 06-11 07:07:10.033: D/com.example.lifecycle.LifeLogger(600):
>   onCreateView event 06-11 07:07:10.033:
>   D/com.example.lifecycle.LifeLogger(600): onCreateView event 06-11
>   07:07:10.043: D/com.example.lifecycle.LifeLogger(600): onCreateView
>   event 06-11 07:07:10.053: D/com.example.lifecycle.LifeLogger(600):
>   onCreateView event 06-11 07:07:10.063:
>   D/com.example.lifecycle.LifeLogger(600): onCreateView event 06-11
>   07:07:10.063: D/com.example.lifecycle.LifeLogger(600): onCreateView
>   event 06-11 07:07:10.063: D/com.example.lifecycle.LifeLogger(600):
>   onCreateView event 06-11 07:07:10.063:
>   D/com.example.lifecycle.LifeLogger(600): onCreateView event 06-11
>   07:07:10.073: D/com.example.lifecycle.LifeLogger(600): onCreateView
>   event 06-11 07:07:10.073: D/com.example.lifecycle.LifeLogger(600):
>   onCreateView event 06-11 07:07:10.083:
>   D/com.example.lifecycle.LifeLogger(600): onCreateView event 06-11
>   07:07:10.083: D/com.example.lifecycle.LifeLogger(600): onCreateView
>   event 06-11 07:07:10.083: D/com.example.lifecycle.LifeLogger(600):
>   onCreateView event 06-11 07:07:10.093:
>   D/com.example.lifecycle.LifeLogger(600): onCreateView event 06-11
>   07:07:10.093: D/com.example.lifecycle.LifeLogger(600): onCreateView
>   event 06-11 07:07:10.093: D/com.example.lifecycle.LifeLogger(600):
>   onCreateView event 06-11 07:07:10.103:
>   D/com.example.lifecycle.LifeLogger(600): onCreateView event 06-11
>   07:07:10.113: D/com.example.lifecycle.LifeLogger(600): onCreateView
>   event 06-11 07:07:10.113: D/com.example.lifecycle.LifeLogger(600):
>   onCreateView event 06-11 07:07:10.113:
>   D/com.example.lifecycle.LifeLogger(600): onCreate event 06-11
>   07:07:10.113: D/com.example.lifecycle.LifeLogger(600): onStart event
>   06-11 07:07:10.113: D/com.example.lifecycle.LifeLogger(600): onResume
>   event 06-11 07:07:10.193: D/com.example.lifecycle.LifeLogger(600):
>   onCreateView event 06-11 07:07:10.223: D/gralloc_goldfish(600):
>   Emulator without GPU emulation detected. 06-11 07:08:19.633:
>   D/com.example.lifecycle.LifeLogger(600): onPause event 06-11
>   07:08:20.213: D/com.example.lifecycle.LifeLogger(600): onStop event
>   06-11 07:08:31.993: D/com.example.lifecycle.LifeLogger(600): onRestart
>   event 06-11 07:08:31.993: D/com.example.lifecycle.LifeLogger(600):
>   onStart event 06-11 07:08:31.993:
>   D/com.example.lifecycle.LifeLogger(600): onResume event 06-11
>   07:08:51.073: D/com.example.lifecycle.LifeLogger(600): onPause event
>   06-11 07:08:52.963: D/com.example.lifecycle.LifeLogger(600): onStop
>   event 06-11 07:08:54.043: D/com.example.lifecycle.LifeLogger(600):
>   onDestroy event

What happened here? why is onCreateView is called so many times?

What is the timing of onCreateView?

Thanks.

update:

the xml inflated:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

the manifast:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.lifecycle"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.lifecycle.LifeLogger"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

run on android api level 16

Comment: Can I see your activity_life_logger.xml file

Comment: see the activity lifecycle. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: Try to log the name of the created view like this: `Log.d(TAG,"onCreateView event: " + name);`. Then we can see which views are being added.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You have extended your class with `Activity`. That means your class' lifecycle would be as below.

[image]

So, onCreateView is not a lifecycle method for activity. It's just a member method which will be used for specified tasks as said in doc.

> Standard implementation of
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.Factory.onCreateView used when inflating
>   with the LayoutInflater returned by getSystemService. This
>   implementation does nothing and is for
>   pre-android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB apps. Newer apps should
>   use onCreateView(View, String, Context, AttributeSet).

To rely on the call of onCreateView() in an Activity is bad programming.

If you were using `Fragment` extended to your class and have written onCreateView() method, then it would have been called only twice after your onAttach() and onDestroyView() if you are still on same fragment.

See this diagram.

[image]

Here, it's a method of lifecycle for Fragment.

So, you are testing with wrong assumptions. That's all!

Answer (score 4):

Android Framework uses mechanism of Dependencies injection When layout file is inflated.I think due to this onCreateView is called so many times.Formula for this might be as below

- **no of view in layout xml == no of calls to onCreateView**

Try to remove setContentView and see how many times onCreateView is called.You might get some insights into it.

Answer (score 3):

You can monitor the reason onCreateView gets Called from a log file :

add inside your onCreateView method this  :

```
Log.d("TAG", "onCreateView event : " + name);
```

such as my logcat produce this ;

```
onCreateView : LinearLayout
onCreateView : ViewStub
onCreateView : FrameLayout
onCreateView : android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout
onCreateView : android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout
onCreateView : android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer
onCreateView : android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
onCreateView : android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContextView
onCreateView : LinearLayout
```

Answer (score 0):

`onCreateView` calls = number of views in layout (create each view)