# Trying to pass data from one fragment to another but data does not appear

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have an activity with 2 fragments, one handles all data and other is only like a scoreboard.

Fragment1 asks for a new player name when one player is out, and fragment2 will use the name for the scoreboard.
I'm using a static method in fragment1 getPlayerName() and using it in fragment2.

The app consists of a ListView + custom ArrayAdapter combo to populate the fragment2.

Here's the simplified code with required details, it doesn't show errors but doesn't work. I press out, enter the new name, but it doesn't show up in the Scoreboard.

Tried notifydatasetchanged() at various places but seems like that isn't the solution.

FieldFragment.java

```
public class FieldFragment extends Fragment {

static String playerNames[] = new String[11];
    int i = 0;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_field, container, false);

        Button out = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.out);
        out.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                displayDialog();
            }
        });

        return rootView;


    }

public void displayDialog(){
        final Dialog nameDialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
        nameDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

        Button ok = (Button)nameDialog.findViewById(R.id.ok_button);
        ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText nameET = (EditText)nameDialog.findViewById(R.id.name_edit_text);
                playerNames[i] = nameET.getText().toString();
                nameDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });


        Button cancel = (Button)nameDialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                nameDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        nameDialog.show();
    }

    public static String getPlayerName(int playerNumber) {

        return playerNames[playerNumber];
    }
}
```

And ScoreboardFragment:

```
public class ScoreboardFragment extends Fragment {

    public ScoreboardFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    PlayerAdapter playerAdapter;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scoreboard, container, false);

        int i=0;

        ArrayList<Players> players = new ArrayList<>();
        players.add(new Players(getPlayerName(i++),0,0));
        players.add(new Players(getPlayerName(i++),0,0));

        playerAdapter = new PlayerAdapter(getActivity(), players);
        ListView playerList = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_of_players);
        playerList.setAdapter(playerAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

What's wrong with the code?

Let know if you need more files

Answer (score 0):

A fragment is a weak controller, also avoid using static variables for passing data.

On the other side, An Activity must have a controller on all the fragments inside it.

One thing that might be your problem is that you're reinstanciating the fragments every time you present them.

A cleaner work around is putting the data inside the Activity and then configuring the data using private methods inside the activity from Fragments.

But make sure you're getting the data/activity inside the `onActivityCreated()` method in Fragment; otherwise the activity might be null (on some methods like `onCreateView()` the activity is not yet accessible)

Comment: So you mean send the data to the Activity and getter methods in the Activity that will be called from Fragment2?

Comment: @Abhijeet yes exactly

Answer (score 0):

For passing data between 2 activity with 2 fragments are:

**Pass data to SecondActivity with Intent**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity, SeconActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Player", name);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Receive data inside SecondActivity**

```
String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("Player");
```

**Send Value to ScoreboardFragment when object create**

```
ScoreboardFragment  fragment = new ScoreboardFragment (name);
```

And finally you get the player name. Now you can use the player name wherever you want

Comment: No I'm not dealing with 2 activities, only 1 activity that has 2 fragments

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your code there can be following issues:

1. you are not incrementing `i` in `FieldFragment`, so after every change player name is added to 0th location.
2. As you are showing some dialog to get player name if `ScoreboardFragment` is already created `onResume()` will be called.

So please check if `onCreateView()` is getting called to update name. 
For more details check [onCreateView method gets called when? and How many times in Activity life cycle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24156926/oncreateview-method-gets-called-when-and-how-many-times-in-activity-life-cycle)

Comment: 1. Well, made the i global. 
2. I don't know how that will matter, but anyway, I tried onResume(), doesn't help

Comment: You can use callback mechanism for passing data between fragments. For more info:  http://www.journaldev.com/14207/android-passing-data-between-fragments